# Why do matplotlib spines have a "set_label" and "get_label" methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I noticed that spines in matplotlib have `get_label` and `set_label` methods:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f, a = plt.subplots()
label = a.spines['top'].get_label()
```

Was just wondering what the purpose of this is, given that `XAxis` and `YAxis` have `Text` object labels that are modified when calling the useful command `a.set_xlabel()` and `a.set_ylabel()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label you can set or get with `.get_label` and `.set_label` on the spines **is not** the xlabel or ylabel you can set or get for the axes.

It is rather the label that every artist in matplotlib has.

`matplotlib.spines.Spine` subclasses `matplotlib.patches.Patch`.
`matplotlib.patches.Patch` subclasses `matplotlib.artist.Artist`.

So a Spine is an Artist and every `matplotlib.artist.Artist` has a  `label` and a getter and setter for it. This label is not used in many cases, but can be used for some artists, e.g. to create a legend entry or label it for other purposes. In that sense it's just an attribute of the object which may or may not be used.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I suspected; interesting.